# What are the good solutions for GUID?

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb

Currently, I have a database with 13 millions rows and we use `uuid` as the primary key. Everytime we do a database migration, it takes hours to finish a table. The query performance seems to be poor as well.

After Googling and reading some blogs, they recommended converting from `uuid` to `binary(16)`, but the converted value is unreadable and very awkward to use. It's also hard to use in my Ruby code.

Is there an alternative solution to get a globally unique identifer in MySQL beside `uuid`?

```
mysql> select UNHEX(REPLACE('A4E7890F-A188-4663-89EB-176D94DF6774','-',''));
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| UNHEX(REPLACE('A4E7890F-A188-4663-89EB-176D94DF6774','-','')) |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| ���Fc��m��gt                                                       |
```

I checked, and mongodb also has `ObjectId` which is only 12 bytes. Is it possible to use that in MySQL server? How could I take advantage of that to use in MySQL?

Comment: I suggest first breaking your large table into several smaller ones. That'll help with migrations at the cost of little code complexity.

Comment: It's a database for 200 portals, that table is for those portals. If I split, I should split into 200 databases. That means I would need to do maintenance quite alot.

Comment: Why 200 databases? You could divide them in groups and create, say, 10-20 tables (databases)

Comment: each table belongs to all tables. if it needs to split, split them all together right?

Comment: Not necessarily. You can also split them differently (one table becomes 10 tables, and another one - 20).

Comment: well, it will difficult to do reporting because the data scatters around.

Comment: Yes, but migrations run faster. And you can always keep splitting (and moving data to another machine). Messing with data formats has much lesser effect.

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer

You will have to test this for your application, but with really large datasets I would expect performance to improve if you:

1. Use an [AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) column for your primary key, since MySQL is optimized for that.
2. Index your UUID column so that you can do fast lookups without a full table scan.

Comparing lengthy UUIDs can't possibly be as efficient as integer keys, so you should definitely get a performance boost this way even if you're still using the UUID column heavily. There's no substitute for benchmarking it yourself, though.

#### Related Question

[UUID performance in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365132/uuid-performance-in-mysql)

Comment: It's his migrations that are slow, not queries.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev The OP says "The query performance seems to be poor as well." Please feel free to offer a better answer if you have one; I'll certainly upvote anything that addresses the problem better than my recommendation.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Didn't notice that one.

Comment: My answer (in the comments) is: "split the tables and get more machines". But I hesitate to post it as an answer. :)