# Stored Procedure slower than equivalent query

Tags: mysql

Why is it that this stored procedure:

```
CREATE
    DEFINER = mysql_user@`%` PROCEDURE sp_GetSessionData(IN SessionId varchar(45))
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM sessiondata WHERE SessionGuid = SessionId;
END;
```

Takes 5 minutes to run but this equivalent query:

```
SELECT * FROM sessiondata WHERE SessionGuid = 'd2c26d6d-4e80-4e80-4e80-2d7ca9cfa3a3';
```

Only takes 40ms to run?

I have an index on the `SessionGuid` column and the column is of type `varchar(45)` which is the exact same as the input parameter for my stored procedure.

**UPDATE:**

Here is what I get when I put an `EXPLAIN` in the stored procedure:

```
╔════╦═════════════╦══════════╦════════════╦══════╦═══════════════╦══════╦═════════╦══════╦══════════╦══════════╦═════════════╗
║ id ║ select_type ║  table   ║ partitions ║ type ║ possible_keys ║ key  ║ key_len ║ ref  ║   rows   ║ filtered ║    Extra    ║
╠════╬═════════════╬══════════╬════════════╬══════╬═══════════════╬══════╬═════════╬══════╬══════════╬══════════╬═════════════╣
║  1 ║ SIMPLE      ║ perfinfo ║ NULL       ║ ALL  ║ NULL          ║ NULL ║ NULL    ║ NULL ║ 77249445 ║      100 ║ Using where ║
╚════╩═════════════╩══════════╩════════════╩══════╩═══════════════╩══════╩═════════╩══════╩══════════╩══════════╩═════════════╝
```

And here is an `EXPLAIN` of the `sessiondata` table:

```
╔═════════════════╦══════════════════╦══════╦═════╦═════════╦════════════════╗
║      Field      ║       Type       ║ Null ║ Key ║ Default ║     Extra      ║
╠═════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════╬═════╬═════════╬════════════════╣
║ PerfId          ║ int(11) unsigned ║ NO   ║ PRI ║ NULL    ║ auto_increment ║
║ SessionGuid     ║ varchar(45)      ║ NO   ║ MUL ║ NULL    ║                ║
║ BuildId         ║ int(11)          ║ NO   ║ MUL ║ NULL    ║                ║
║ Metric          ║ float            ║ NO   ║     ║ NULL    ║                ║
║ MetricId        ║ int(11) unsigned ║ NO   ║ MUL ║ NULL    ║                ║
║ Location        ║ varchar(45)      ║ NO   ║     ║ NULL    ║                ║
║ RunTypeId       ║ int(11)          ║ NO   ║     ║ NULL    ║                ║
║ MetaContextId   ║ int(11)          ║ NO   ║ MUL ║ -1      ║                ║
║ SecondsFromBoot ║ int(10) unsigned ║ NO   ║     ║ NULL    ║                ║
║ Timestamp       ║ datetime         ║ NO   ║     ║ NULL    ║                ║
║ DeviceId        ║ int(11)          ║ NO   ║ MUL ║ -1      ║                ║
╚═════════════════╩══════════════════╩══════╩═════╩═════════╩════════════════╝
```

Comment: Can you show the table structure for `sessiondata` i.e does it have a column `SessionId`? You can also use `EXPLAIN` inside the procedure to show the query plan.

Comment: @slaakso Added the requested info the OP

Comment: Is the sessiondata a view or why the sp EXPLAIN says the table is `perfinfo`? Also, do you mix character sets (database, table, connection)?

Comment: I'd suggest you have a look at this article:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365132/uuid-performance-in-mysql

Comment: @slaakso The table is actually called `perfinfo` sorry for the confusion. As for mixing character sets I have no clue -- how can I check?

Comment: @ChrisFNZ Can you explain what part of this article is supposed to answer my question?

Comment: It talks about the performance implications of the datatype used to store a uid.  In particular the comment in a beige box (with 25 votes) looked like it might be relevant in your case.  Theoretically if you're feeding the SP the same SessionGuid = value as the SELECT query, the performance should be identical (well certainly not slower).

Comment: @ChrisFNZ Right, I understand the implications of using uids from the article but like you said the performance difference with a literal vs a variable doesn't make sense still.

Comment: I know it sounds odd but can you try deleting the SP and then recreating it without the definer clause? i.e. CREATE PROCEDURE...

Answer (score 0):

To see if a difference in character set / collation is causing the sp query not to use and index, see if there is difference in the settings:

To see the info on the column:

```
select CHARACTER_SET_NAME, COLLATION_NAME 
from information_schema.COLUMNS 
where TABLE_SCHEMA='*YOURDATABASENAME*' 
  and TABLE_NAME='sessiondata' and COLUMN_NAME='SessionGuid';
```

To see the info on the sp's parameter:

```
select CHARACTER_SET_NAME, COLLATION_NAME 
from information_schema.PARAMETERS 
where SPECIFIC_SCHEMA='*YOURDATABASENAME*' 
  and SPECIFIC_NAME='sp_GetSessionData' and PARAMETER_NAME='SessionId';
```

And finally the connection details:

```
show variables where variable_name like 'character_set%' 
  or variable_name like '%collation%';
```

Ideally the `SessionGuid`'s character set could be a set to `'ascii'` so more values would fit in cache.