# What's the performance impact of using a varchar(190) as a primary key for all tables in a MYSQL database?

Tags: mysql

Imagine you have a dozen tables with each table using a UUID-ish varchar(190) as a primary key and most tables having 1-4 varchar(190) FKs to other tables in the database. Table sizes are expected to grow to millions of entries.

I've been searching around looking for recommendations but I'm struggling to find anything definitive apart from potentially insertion costs to random keys. I understand there are trade-offs to using UUIDs as database primary keys, but what I'm particularly interested in is whether having such a large 190 varchar based UUID in particular will cause additional performance issues. I did find information about index prefixes which would lead me to believe that there is a performance impact. I'm guessing that it could result in really big indexes and lower performance, but I'd like to know for sure.

Comment: Have you already reviewed  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365132/uuid-performance-in-mysql ?

Comment: @PM77-1 thanks for the pointer.  I hadn't seen that one in particular but it looks like similar trade offs to the varchar searches I've run. What I'm wondering is if there's something particularly degenerate about having a really large varchar as a key that would make it unambiguously bad.

Comment: The longer the key, the worse the performance. Simple as that. I don't know what other kind of answer you're expecting here.

Comment: I'm just hoping for something more specific. if queries or inserts are going to be 1-5% slower maybe I don't care, if the impact is an order of magnitude more than that than it's clear it's not the right way to go.

Comment: The impact of UUID is bigger than the length of the key.  Being both UUID and long is a double whammy.  I can devise a case where UUID slows down things by _10x_; length is only a few _percent_.

Comment: I can even devise a case a slowdown due to artificially adding an AUTO_INCREMENT in place of a... perfectly good (albeit long) index

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/73546838/1766831

Comment: I can discuss further when and why length matters; but you will have to start another question that makes no mention of UUIDs.

Comment: Thanks @RickJames your response WRT UUIDs being an order of magnitude greater than length is really what I wanted to know.  My concern was that length could have a greater than linear impact on performance.

Comment: @elchuppa - In general, `VARCHAR(n)` performs identically regardless of the value of `n`.  The tipping points are for n>191.  VARCHAR stores the values as a 1- or 2-byte _actual_ length, plus the necessary bytes.  So, for a given set of strings, the bytes on disk are identical for different values on n.

Comment: @RickJames thanks for the clarification I hadn't realized that the 191 was the new 255 :) https://www.grouparoo.com/blog/varchar-191

Comment: @elchuppa - The 191 goes away with 5.7.  "255" as a max shows up in at least 2 ways over the years.  More "limits":  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits